# How to make a tooltip with the same look and feel as when we add "title" attribute to an element?

Tags: javascript, html, css, accessibility

I am trying to replicate the look and feel of the tooltip when we add the "title" attribute to an element.

- Tooltip should be hovarable
- Tooltip should be dismissable by pressing the Esc key

Currently, my custom tooltip is not hoverable. Also the look and feel is not matched with - https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_global_title

Any help is really appreciated and thanks in advance

```js
const tooltipTrigger = document.querySelector(".tooltip-trigger");
const tooltipText = document.querySelector(".tooltip-text");

tooltipTrigger.addEventListener("mouseenter", showTooltip);
tooltipTrigger.addEventListener("mouseleave", hideTooltip);
tooltipText.addEventListener("keydown", dismissTooltip);

function showTooltip() {
  tooltipText.style.visibility = "visible";
}

function hideTooltip() {
  tooltipText.style.visibility = "hidden";
}

function dismissTooltip(event) {
  if (event.keyCode === 27) {
    tooltipText.style.visibility = "hidden";
  }
}
```

```css
.tooltip-text {
    visibility: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #000;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 4px;
    z-index: 1;
}

.tooltip-trigger{
    cursor: pointer;
}

.tooltip-trigger:hover .tooltip-text {
    visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
    <title>Tooltip</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <span class="tooltip-trigger" aria-describedby="tooltip-text"
      >Hover over me</span
    >
    <div id="tooltip-text" class="tooltip-text" role="tooltip">
      This is the tooltip text
    </div>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Default look of title element is different for each browser

Comment: @Konrad thanks for pointing that out, any idea how to fix that styling because for the "title" attribute it's places a bit on the left side with a bit spacing below the triggering element

Comment: Native `title` element position the tooltip it according to cursor

Comment: @Konrad can we make that happen?

Comment: Just out of curiosity - Why do you want to persist the hover on a tooltip? - PS, don't use w3schools as a truthful source of programming best practices.

Comment: Because it's needed to satisfy the SC 1.14.13. is it possible to achieve that?

Comment: How to make it reusable @RokoC.Buljan

Comment: By using `tooltipTrigger.forEach((elTrigger) => { /*logic for each elTrigger element*/ });`

Answer (score 0):

```js
const tooltipTrigger = document.querySelector(".tooltip-trigger");
const tooltipText = document.querySelector(".tooltip-text");

let timeout = null;

tooltipTrigger.addEventListener("mouseenter", showTooltip);
tooltipTrigger.addEventListener("mouseleave", hideTooltip);
window.addEventListener("keydown", dismissTooltip);

function showTooltip(event) {
  timeout = setTimeout(() => {
    tooltipText.style.visibility = "visible";
    tooltipText.style.left = `${event.clientX}px`
    tooltipText.style.top = `${event.clientY}px`
  }, 1000)
}

function hideTooltip() {
  clearTimeout(timeout);
  timeout = null;
  tooltipText.style.visibility = "hidden";
}

function dismissTooltip(event) {
  if (event.key === 'Escape') {
    tooltipText.style.visibility = "hidden";
  }
}
```

```css
.tooltip-text {
  visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 4px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.tooltip-trigger {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
  <title>Tooltip</title>
</head>

<body>
  <span class="tooltip-trigger" aria-describedby="tooltip-text">Hover over me</span
    >
    <div id="tooltip-text" class="tooltip-text" role="tooltip">
      This is the tooltip text
    </div>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: @Konard thanks for this. I am not able to get the tooltips dismissed by pressing the Esc key. Am I doing something wrong with mu code?

Comment: @thelonelyCoder click anywhere before hovering. You have to focus the page to make it work. It will work without clicking in the actual website

Comment: its working. great. But sometimes it's like this - https://ibb.co/0Z8s6wK

Comment: Any idea on how to position the tooltip like the "title" attribute? Because now sometime the tooltip is overlapping with the element text

Comment: It overlaps with the default title as well https://imgur.com/l1Z9o2S

Comment: Yes, but would it be possible with some style tweaks to not do that? That would be a great help actually.

Comment: Also, how to preserve the hover state, for the tooltip? any idea on that?

Comment: You forgot that you need to min-max the tooltip's X/Y coordinates - to reposition the tooltip  in order to not go out of the viewport boundary. Also to add to the Y position to not cover the hovered element... Also - the hover is not persisted... Also, the code will work for one element only. Shouldn't we write reusable code?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan *the hover is not persisted* - I don't get that one

Comment: @Konrad as an extra feature, OP needs (but showed no code to support) is that if the mouse enters the Tooltip, it should persist, not hide. imagine you need a link inside that tooltip, you cannot click it because if the mouse leaves the target - the tooltip disappears.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan is it possible to achieve that both the overlapping issue for tooltip and to make the tooltip hoverable?

Answer (score 0):

The ultimate answer is in fact, you can't.

You can't replicate the exact behavior of a tooltip generated by a title attribute, simply because their appearance and behavior can be dramatically different across browsers, devices and OS.

You can certainly try to approach very close what it looks like on a particular browser/device/OS, but won't probably be able to replicate exactly everything everywhere. Note that doing user agent detection to finetune is most often a bad idea.